# Replace specific character and getting index in Java

Tags: java, string

I have tried a code to replace only specific character. In the string there are three same characters, and I want to replace the second or third character only. For example:

```
String line = "this.a[i] = i";
```

In this string there are three 'i' characters. I want to replace the second or third character only. So, the string will be

```
 String line = "this.a[i] = "newChar";
```

This is my code to read the string and replace it by another string:

```
String EQ_VAR;

EQ_VAR = getequals(line);
int length = EQ_VAR.length();

if(length == 1){
    int gindex = EQ_VAR.indexOf(EQ_VAR);

    StringBuilder nsb = new StringBuilder(line);
    nsb.replace(gindex, gindex, "New String");
}
```

The method to get the character:

```
String getequals(String str){
     int startIdx = str.indexOf("=");
    int endIdx = str.indexOf(";");

    String content = str.substring(startIdx + 1, endIdx);
    return content;
}
```

I just assume that using an index is the best option to replace a specific character. I have tried using String `replace` but then all 'i' characters are replaced and the result string look like this:

```
String line = "th'newChar's.a[newChar] = newChar";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could accomplish replacing all occurances except first few:

```
    String str = "This is a text containing many i many iiii = i";
    String replacement = "hua";
    String toReplace = str.substring(str.indexOf("=")+1, str.length()).trim(); // Yup, gets stuff after "=".
    int charsToNotReplace = 1; // Will ignore these number of chars counting from start of string

    // First replace all the parts
    str = str.replaceAll(toReplace, replacement);

    // Then replace "charsToNotReplace" number of occurrences back with original chars.
    for(int i = 0; i < charsToNotReplace; i++)
        str = str.replaceFirst(replacement, toReplace);

    // Just trim from "="
    str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("=")-1);

    System.out.println(str);
```

Result: `This huas a text contahuanhuang many hua many huahuahuahua;`

You set set `charsToNotReplace` to however number of first number of chars you want to ignore. For example setting it to 2 will ignore replacing first two occurrences (well, technically).